# PowerShell SharePoint Online ExecuteQuery Error - Timed Out

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, csom

This one has been puzzling me for days now... It works more than half the time, but will often give me this error upon calling the ExecuteQuery() command:

> Exception calling "ExecuteQuery" with "0" argument(s): "The operation has timed out"

The PowerShell:

```
$ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($webURL) 
$ctx.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Credentials.UserName,$Credentials.Password) 

$web = $ctx.Web  
$ctx.Load($web) 

#Retrieve Library
$list = $ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($ITPurchaseRequestListName)
$ctx.load($list)

$files = $list.rootFolder.files
$ctx.load($files)
$ctx.executeQuery()

##########
if((test-path $tempPath) -eq $False)
{
    new-item -itemtype directory -path $temppath
}

foreach($file in $files)
{
    $ctx.load($file)
    $ctx.executeQuery()

    $fileRef = $file.ServerRelativeURL
    $fileInfo = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File]::OpenBinaryDirect($ctx, $fileRef);

    $fileName = $tempPath + $file.Name
    $fileStream = [System.IO.File]::Create($fileName)
    $fileInfo.Stream.CopyTo($fileStream);

    $fileStream.Close()

    start-sleep -seconds 2
}
```

If I kill the console session and start a new PowerShell window, it'll work for a few runs and then conk out again. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the other comments and suggestions, the folks at 6sc.com were able to help me identify the root cause which was a missing stream.close() in the for loop.

```
foreach($file in $results)
{

    $fileRef = $file["FileRef"];
    $fileName = $tempPath + $file["FileLeafRef"];

    $fileInfo = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File]::OpenBinaryDirect($ctx, $fileRef);
    $fileStream = [System.IO.File]::Create($fileName);
    $fileInfo.Stream.CopyTo($fileStream);

    $fileStream.Close();
    $fileInfo.Stream.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that calling executeQuery () with a foreach statement is not good for performance.
It is better to use "Include" to load the properties of the file object outside the foreach statement.

Reference URL

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/office/ee539350(v=office.14).aspx#Anchor_5

Answer (score 0):

Add a TRY..CATCH block to your PowerShell script and it will be handling the server time-out, which will provide continuity execution.

The other benefit of the TRY...CATCH, you will be able to have the details of the exception and you can capture on a separate log file, giving you additional clues about the problem. Right now it is hard to make an educated guess, files handles could be in use, server I/O, a file might be open in exclusive mode, connection might have been broken for a short time, hard to tell.

With the TRY..CATCH capturing the date and time + details of the exception will help you to open up Windows Event Viewer and find out with precision what happened.

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather use `.OpenBinaryStream()`, download it into memory, and then save to disc.

Code:

```
foreach($file in $files)
{
    $data = $file.OpenBinaryStream();
    $ctx.Load($file);
    $ctx.ExecuteQuery();

    $memory = new-object system.io.MemoryStream
    $buffer = new-object system.byte[](1024*64)
    $pos = 0;
    while (($pos = $data.Value.Read($buffer, 0, $buffer.Length)) -gt 0)
    {
        $memory.Write($buffer, 0, $pos);
    }
    $memory.Seek(0, [System.IO.SeekOrigin]::Begin);   

    $fileStream = [System.IO.File]::Create($fileName)
    $memory.CopyTo($fileStream)
    $memory.Close()
    $fileStream.Close()
}
```

Answer (score -1):

include `$fileInfo.Stream.Close();` that will do magic.