# Skip error and exception time-outs in for...each loops Powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, foreach, error-handling, try-catch

I'm quite new to PS-scripting. I need to download files and folders from Sharepoint using Powershell. The script I have works fine, but it stops running when there is an error/exception. I already removed the try/catch which makes the script continue running after an error/exception, but it still has long time-outs before downloading the next file. And in fact I would like to keep catching the errors so I can log the names of the files that caused an error in a txt-file or so.

What is the best way to do all of this?

```
Function Download-SPOFolder()
{
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string] $SiteURL,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Folder] $SourceFolder,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string] $TargetFolder
    )

    Try {
        #Create Local Folder, if it doesn't exist
        $FolderName = ($SourceFolder.ServerRelativeURL) -replace "/","\"
        $LocalFolder = $TargetFolder + $FolderName
        If (!(Test-Path -Path $LocalFolder)) {
                New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $LocalFolder | Out-Null
        }

        #Get all Files from the folder
        $FilesColl = $SourceFolder.Files
        $Ctx.Load($FilesColl)
        $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()

        #Iterate through each file and download
        Foreach($File in $FilesColl)
        {
            $TargetFile = $LocalFolder+"\"+$File.Name

            #Download the fileS
            $FileInfo = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File]::OpenBinaryDirect($Ctx,$File.ServerRelativeURL)
            $WriteStream = [System.IO.File]::Open($TargetFile,[System.IO.FileMode]::Create)
            $FileInfo.Stream.CopyTo($WriteStream)
            $WriteStream.Close()
            write-host -f Green "Downloaded File:"$TargetFile
        }

        #Process Sub Folders
        $SubFolders = $SourceFolder.Folders
        $Ctx.Load($SubFolders)
        $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
        Foreach($Folder in $SubFolders)
        {
            If($Folder.Name -ne "Forms")
            {
                #Call the function recursively
                Download-SPOFolder -SiteURL $SiteURL -SourceFolder $Folder -TargetFolder $TargetFolder
            }
        }
     }
    Catch {
        $msg = $Error[0].Exception.Message
        write-host -f Red "Error Downloading Folder! - $msg"
    }
}

#Set parameter values
$orgName="myOrgName"
$admin="myUsrName"
$SiteURL="myUrl"
$FolderRelativeUrl="myFolderUrl"
$TargetFolder="C:\Temp"

#Setup Credentials to connect
$cred  = Get-Credential -UserName $admin -Message GlobalAdminLogin
Connect-SPOService -Url https://$orgName-admin.sharepoint.com -Credential $cred
$Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Cred.Username, $Cred.Password)

#Setup the context
$Ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL)
$Ctx.Credentials = $Credentials

#Get the Web
$Web = $Ctx.Web
$Ctx.Load($Web)
$Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
$Web.ServerRelativeUrl+$FolderRelativeUrl

#Get the Folder

$SourceFolder = $Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl($Web.ServerRelativeUrl+$FolderRelativeUrl)
$Ctx.Load($SourceFolder)
$Ctx.ExecuteQuery()

#Call the function to download Folder
Download-SPOFolder -SiteURL $SiteURL -SourceFolder $SourceFolder -TargetFolder $TargetFolder
```

Comment: I think your issue is you are doing  much in one ```try```. If you have a problem in any part of the ```try``` it goes to the ```catch```. break into smaller ```try and catch ``` so you can narrow the problem down and get what you want.

Comment: Thx for your comment, but I narrowed the try...catch already by putting it in my first foreach loop and there it is the same. But that's not the problem, the fact is that I want the looping to continue after the script passed the catch, I want it to be non-terminating. The catch I need to log the probematic files.

Comment: I am not a pro but I think this bit ```Foreach($File in $FilesColl)
        {
            $TargetFile = $LocalFolder+"\"+$File.Name

            #Download the fileS
            $FileInfo = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File]::OpenBinaryDirect($Ctx,$File.ServerRelativeURL)
            $WriteStream = [System.IO.File]::Open($TargetFile,[System.IO.FileMode]::Create)
            $FileInfo.Stream.CopyTo($WriteStream)
            $WriteStream.Close()
            write-host -f Green "Downloaded File:"$TargetFile
        }``` needs its own ```try/catch```

Comment: The problem was not with my code, but with some file paths that were to long (>260 char), which I could fix by setting the LongPathEnable to 'true' in the registry of my machine. -> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem

Comment: After activating the LongPathEnable I still encountered terminating errors like 404's, found the solution to that in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45343993/powershell-sharepoint-online-executequery-error-timed-out